# Get hostname from connected client - tcp socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Im writing a python script where there is a incoming tcp socket connection.

Would like to retrieve the connected clients hostname (for example : ESP32-XYZ)

Only know to get the hostname on the client itself by using
socket.gethostname()

```
    while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    test = connection.getsockname() # prints ('127.0.0.1', 10000)
    test2 = connection.gethostname() # error has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
```

is it possible to get the hostname from the connection ? Or how should it be handled ?

Since the ip adress of the client might change , I wanted to safe the hostname so I can save it and assign the right ip adress on a new connection.

(Just need a unique identifier)

Comment: *Since the ip adress of the client might change*. The socket only contains an IP address (and a port). You will have to use DNS or static hosts file to convert the IP address to a host name.

Comment: ok that makes it clear ... not what I waas hoping for ... Guess the device needs to send its hostname along then .... instead of it being resolved ...

The device is a Esp32 microcontroller ... pn my local network